# PrimeNg chart label rotation with Angular2

Tags: angular, charts, chart.js, primeng

I have a problem with primeNg chart using angular 2.
I am able to display the chart using the following code in my component:

```js
 fillChartData(data){     
      this.chartData = {
          labels: data.map( x =>  x.nameProcess ),
          datasets: [
              {
                  label: 'error',
                  data: data.map( x =>  x.nbError ),
                  backgroundColor: 'rgba(100,149,237,0.5)',
              }],
           options: {
             animation:{
               animateScale:true
             }
           }
          };
      setTimeout(() =>  this.chart.reinit()); //TODO
  }
```

The code of my html:

```html
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-6">
     <div class="card" >
         <div class="card-content" id="barC">
             <h4 class="title title-centered" >{{title}}</h4>
             <p-chart  #chart2 type="bar" [data]="chartData" (click)="chartClicked($event)"></p-chart>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

And the chart I got on browser:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fSPP.png)

But now I want to display the x-labels horizontally and not as they showed up.
Is there any way to rotate the x-label in order to display them horizontally?
I look closely in primeNgCharts and chart.js documentations but I'm not able to find something who actually give me wanted behaviour.

Comment: wat is the final json you get for your **datasets** array. Update what is the value of `nbError`

Comment: `nbError` is a `number`. The final json look like `{[nameProcess: string, nbError: number]}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for @jordanwillis
I solved this Issue by migrating from primeng charts to ng2charts which use chart.js>2.0 version. This allow me to perform advanced customisation to my charts labels/font-size/rotation..

Answer (score 1):

In chart.js, scale tick label rotation is performed automatically and is determined by how much space is available for each label.  If there is not enough room to fit the labels horizontally, then they will be rotated.

The image of your chart looks fairly small compared with the size of your scale labels.  If you can increase the size of your chart then they will probably appear horizontally.

If changing the size is not an option, then check out the `minRotation` and `maxRotation` tick options.  You can use these to properties to specify how much  the labels should rotate when they don't fit.  Note, the options are only used when the label is actually rotated (e.g. they will have no affect on labels that are small enough to first horizontally).

You can configure these properties inside of the `scales.ticks`.  It would look something like this.

```
fillChartData(data){     
  this.chartData = {
    labels: data.map( x =>  x.nameProcess ),
    datasets: [{
      label: 'error',
      data: data.map( x =>  x.nbError ),
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(100,149,237,0.5)',
    }],
    options: {
      animation:{
        animateScale:true
      },
      scales: [{
        yAxes: {
          ticks: {
            minRotation: 0,
            maxRotation: 0,
          }
        }
      }]
    }
  };

  setTimeout(() =>  this.chart.reinit()); //TODO
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply @jordanwillis . You're rigth, by increasing significally the size I'am able to see it display horizontally. However this is not an option in my current case. I've also  tried to configure de yAxes and even xAxes  as you've specified but the final results remains the same.

Comment: It looks like PrimeNg is [using a very old version of chart.js](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/10f360d4c9b00c9983314f2c7b984435791cd7ed/index.html#L46) (v2.1.3). The current version is v2.5.0.  I'm guessing the rotation options are not implemented in v2.1.3 and this is why it does not work fir you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this information. I think I would try to use highcharts-ng then or just come back to chart.js (without primeng) if it will solve my problem